# Are Browsers Loading Same Scripts Multiple Times?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am experimenting on a web page generation tool, and in some cases it happens that the same script is getting included multiple times (because of certain dependencies). Should I worry about it or it is solved on browser level that the exact same file won't be loaded multiple times

Example in page code:

```html
<script src="../../Scripts/thescript.js"></script>
...
...
<script src="../../Scripts/thescript.js"></script>
...
..
<script src="../../Scripts/thescript.js"></script>
```

How many times *thescript.js* would be loaded?

This question looks like a duplicate of 
[Will inserting the same `<script>` into the DOM twice cause a second request in any browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464961/will-inserting-the-same-script-into-the-dom-twice-cause-a-second-request-in)

However, that was 6 years ago, browsers changed a lot and it might not be relevant anymore, and it does not have accepted answer anyway. So I would like to keep this open, and hopefully get some good advice.

As a quick test I made this small page code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='../Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script> 
    <script src='../Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    PAGE BODY
    <script src='../Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>
    <script src='../Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script> 
    <script src='../Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script> 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In **Chrome** (Version: 49.0.2623.110 m) if I inspect:
[image]

I get what I hoped for.

In **Edge** (Version: 25.10586.0.0): 
[image]

Not really what I hoped for. But the loading time is getting better.

**Firefox** (Version: 42.0):
[image]

**Internet Explorer** (Version 11.162.10586.0)
[image]

However getting 304 (Not modified) and loading from cache looks good to me.

It looks like for me that today browsers handle this kind of things as expected, so no issue in referencing the exact same js file multiple times in the document. Unless you feel bad for that (0.5 - 1 ms) time spent to figure out whether to load the script or no. Probably going through the document and "cleaning" it would make the performance worse than leaving it. Any other opinion?

Comment: I've done small tests but it is not enough to try out on one setup, and there are much more experienced people out there who might help and give some good advice, that's why we have SO.